# My carousel is not working and the image doesn't show on the website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I copy pasted the carousel code from getbootstrap.com and changed the ID. However, it is still not working. I wonder where I am wrong and what should I fix.

```
<div class="py-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="slide" class="carousel slide">
            <div class="carousel-indicators">
                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#slide" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#slide" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#slide" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active" style="background: url(1.jpeg); height: 600px; background-size: cover">
                    <img src="" class="d-block w-100" alt="slide 1">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item" style="background: url(2.jpeg); height: 600px; background-size: cover">
                    <img src="" class="d-block w-100" alt="slide 2">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item" style="background: url(3.jpeg); height: 600px; background-size: cover">
                    <img src="" class="d-block w-100" alt="slide 3">
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#slide" data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#slide" data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>

            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: The image URL needs to be updated as well. Those images will work only on that site. Replace the image URL with any placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Bootstrap JS using CDN and also Bootstrap CSS. You also need to add your image src see below for an example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="py-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="slide" class="carousel slide">
                <div class="carousel-indicators">
                    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#slide" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#slide" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#slide" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active" style='height: 600px; background-size: cover'>
                        <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71ex3MVOFHL._AC_SX679_.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="slide 1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item" style=" height: 600px; background-size: cover">
                        <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71auFznfVpL.__AC_SX300_SY300_QL70_ML2_.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="slide 2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item" style=" height: 600px; background-size: cover">
                        <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71ex3MVOFHL._AC_SX679_.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="slide 3">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#slide" data-bs-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                </button>
                <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#slide" data-bs-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BBtl+eGJRgqQAUMxJ7pMwbEyER4l1g+O15P+16Ep7Q9Q+zqX6gSbd85u4mG4QzX+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```